# How to serve static files from different urls / subdomains?

Tags: django, nginx, subdomain, gunicorn, django-staticfiles

Now my site serves static files from:

**example.com/site_media/pics/1096.jpg**

And I want add second way to upload my files, from url:

**imgs.example.com/pics/1096.jpg**

The both ways must work together (many people have links). How Can I make it works from nginx directly without redirections? I use Django on nginx and gunicorn.

It is possible make it in shared hosting (only Django settings) or I must change it for VPS?

Comment: Django doesn't serve your images, so you need to have control over the nginx configuration to be able to server static files from a subdomain

Comment: ok, I will check nginx configurations

Comment: You should be able to add a second `server` block with your `imgs.example.com` domain that has a location pointing to your static folder that serves the static files